# How to link an additional texture into the shader. LibGDX

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm getting really stucked with this problem.
I need to link a texture to the shader to use it like a displacement map.
Here is my code:

```
//create method
    displacement = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("displacementMap.png"));
    shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("vertexShader.vert"),Gdx.files.internal("fragmentShader.frag"));

    shaderProgram.pedantic = false;
    batch.setShader(shaderProgram);

    shaderProgram.setUniformi("u_texture2",1);
    Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    displacement.bind();
    Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

//render method
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    image.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
```

My fragment shader is:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP
#endif
varying LOWP vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_texture2;
void main(){

vec4 buf = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
gl_FragColor = buf;

}
```

So I realized that the both textures is set to my "image" by changing the `u_texture` to `u_texture2`. 
Hope anybody can help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the shader uniforms, you must first bind the shader:

```
shaderProgram.begin();
shaderProgram.setUniformi("u_texture2",1);
shaderProgram.end();
```

Note the above only has to be done once and the value will stick with the shader.

You're binding the texture correctly, but it's a good idea to do that right before `batch.begin()` in case you are binding some other texture to that texture unit somewhere else in your application. And you must be sure to call `Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);` after binding because SpriteBatch always assumes the active texture has been left at 0.